# Get ID back after array sort?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, sorting

How can I get my giving ID back after sorting the array?

`var distance = [];`

I loop through a JSON file and add the ID and the response (response is the distace between the current user location and the store location) to the array distance: `distance[item.properties.Nid] = response;`.

After each added new distance to the array I sort the array again:

```
sort_stores = function(stores){
    stores = stores.filter(function(item){
        return item !== undefined;
    });

    stores.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;
    });

    console.log(stores);
};
```

But how can I get my ID `distance[item.properties.Nid]` back? When I log `stores` to my console, only the response is logging..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organise your data differently, so that your data has both the ID and the distance in one object.

So, store as follows:

```
distance.push( { Nid: item.properties.Nid, distance: response });
```

And sort with this function:

```
sort_stores = function(stores){
    // NB: first step (filter out undefined) is not needed anymore
    stores.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.distance - b.distance; // add distance property
    });

    console.log(stores);
};
```

To get the distances you can do things like this:

```
firstDistance = stores[0].distance;
```

or loop:

```
for (var store of stores) {
    console.log('Store ', store.Nid, ' is at ', store.distance)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But a quick question, how can I log only the distance now? Can I do it with `console.log(stores.distance)` instead of the whole object?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes indeed, you would get the distance like that, but you need to specify which: `stores[5].distance`. It is also how it is done in the *sort* callback function.

Comment: I added some examples.

Comment: Thanks! You help me a lot with this!